# specific width and height by selecting id selector

Tags: html, css

As far as I know id selector has more specificity, but when I use nivo slider I can't get image size as what I would expect even declaring important.

I included the nivo slider in my div an id with bgslider and I set the css for this

```
#bgslider img{
  position: absolute; 
  width: {some value} !important; 
  height: {some value} !important;
}
```

but also it doesn't work. why?

Comment: display:block?Use firebug and show styles element.

Comment: Post some more code. Does the web inspector cross out some of the styles?

Comment: Post all relevant code

Comment: I'm posting this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EbA2w/  here you could see scroll-bar which you let you know the width and height is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have inline styles in your html which set the width to 1100px causing a scroll bar:

```
<div class="nivoSlider" id="vt_nivo_slider33" style="position: relative; width: 1106px; height: 768px; background: url(&quot;/landmark/images/bg/1.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;">
```

and here:

```
<div class="nivo-slice" style="left: 0px; width: 1106px; height: 100%; opacity: 1; background: url(&quot;/landmark/images/bg/2.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0px 0% transparent;"></div>
```

if you remove that inline width or alter it, there will not be a scroll bar see **demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/fGC5u/

Comment: So, my main question is by selecting by an id has more specificity and also declaring important to them or inline styles?

Comment: id + important wins over inline, so you can also address this via id selector instead of edditing the inline style.

Comment: the images are not causing the scrollbar, its the elements mentioned in my answer.

Comment: in my site, there I set #bgslider img{....} which is not working because of inline styles.

Comment: can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: I'm testing on my localhost.

Comment: if the problem is the scrollbar, ple reread my answer. you need to resize class="nivoSlider" and class="nivo-slice" not just the images

Answer (score 0):

Is it that: inline-styles cannot be overridden with an id selector when inline-styles are controlled by jquery.